# Family and vehicles example using the strategy pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have studied the strategy pattern and understood it w.r.t the example given in the PDF that I referred. I wanted to make sure that my understanding is correct, so I have written a simple program in C++ and designed the strategy pattern using the family and vehicles as the subject. Please provide corrections/suggestions for the program.

```
#include <iostream>

class Vehicle
{
public:
    virtual void useVehicle() = 0;
};

class FordFigo : public Vehicle
{
public:
    void useVehicle()
    {
        std::cout << "Driving FordFigo" << std::endl;
    }
};

class TataNano : public Vehicle
{
public:
    void useVehicle()
    {
        std::cout << "Driving TataNano" << std::endl;
    }
};

class BlackPulsar : public Vehicle
{
public:
    void useVehicle()
    {
        std::cout << "Riding BlackPulsar" << std::endl;
    }
};

class HondaActiva : public Vehicle
{
public:
    void useVehicle()
    {
        std::cout << "Riding HondaActiva" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Family
{
public:
    Vehicle *myVehicle;
    virtual void display() = 0;
    void setVehicle(Vehicle *v)
    {
        myVehicle = v;
    }
    void driveVehicle()
    {
        myVehicle->useVehicle();
    }
};

class Father : public Family
{
public:
    virtual void display()
    {
        std::cout << "I am Father" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Mother : public Family
{
public:
    virtual void display()
    {
        std::cout << "I am Mother" << std::endl;
    }
};


class Son : public Family
{
public:
    virtual void display()
    {
        std::cout << "I am Son" << std::endl;
    }
};


class Daughter : public Family
{
public:
    virtual void display()
    {
        std::cout << "I am Daughter" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Family *fam = new Father();
    fam->display();
    fam->setVehicle(new FordFigo());
    fam->driveVehicle();

    fam = new Daughter();
    fam->display();
    fam->setVehicle(new HondaActiva());
    fam->driveVehicle();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any use of the Strategy Pattern in your code. I would change `Family` to `FamilyMember`. The second one makes more sense to me.

Comment: @RSahu: The strategy is the family mode of transport.

Comment: Exactly @Loki Astari.
Family members shall use the different modes of Vechiles. And vehicles are the Strategies. Currently its having one function only. In future, the implementation may differ. Hence they are separated as interfaces with different algorithms.

Comment: This is a design comment. Your `main()` relies on knowledge of the creation of each Vehicle. As it's a trivial example, this is not a problem. However, use of Strategy in larger projects often begs for a Factory pattern (even Simple Factory) to encapsulate the instantiations of Vehicles (to avoid having dependencies on concrete strategies all over the place). For example, a `create()` method in a simple factory would allow you to call `fam->setVehicle(vehicleFactory.create("FordFigo"));` In other words, only the code inside `create()` knows about the concrete strategies. It's encapsulation.

Comment: I agree with @RSahu that `FamilyMember` is a better name for a class, as a `Family` is an aggregate.

Comment: You don't delete FordFigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "modern C++" it is unusual to see (and use) RAW pointers.

```
class Family
{
public:
    Vehicle *myVehicle;
```

Here you have a pointer to a vehicle. But there is no indication of who owns the vehicle. Does the family member own the vehicle or is a shared resource? Can a family member have no vehicle in which case what is the appropriate response to `driveVehicle()`? Maybe with no vehicle they default to walking?

Anyway. Don't use pointers. In terms of memory management they do not indicate who the owner of the pointed at object is; Note: it is the responsibility of the owner to delete the object. If you don't know who should delete it you have memory leaks (and there is a lot in your code).

Also by default pointers are not set to `NULL`. So if you do not explicitly initialize them in a constructor you have a random value (so initialize them).

What happens if `myVehicle` is `NULL` here?

```
void driveVehicle()
{
    myVehicle->useVehicle();
}
```

You should mark virtual implementations as override

```
void display() override  // indicates this is the implementation
                         // of a virtual function.
{
    std::cout << "I am Daughter" << std::endl;
}
```

Never use dynamic memory memory management when local variables will do.

```
Family *fam = new Father();

// This should be:

Father father;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable review.
I will consider your inputs in my designs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would change `Family` to `FamilyMember`. `FamilyMember` is the better term to be used as a super-class of `Father`, `Mother`, etc.

When I think of the Strategy Pattern I think of a set of concrete classes that implement an algorithm. While your use of `Vehicle` provides a mode of transport to its users, I think use of something like `TransportMode` would make your example more appropriate to be called a user of the Strategy Pattern.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Vehicle
{
public:
    virtual void useVehicle() = 0;
};

class FordFigo : public Vehicle
{
public:
    void useVehicle()
    {
        std::cout << "Driving a Ford Figo." << std::endl;
    }
};

class TataNano : public Vehicle
{
public:
    void useVehicle()
    {
        std::cout << "Driving a Tata Nano." << std::endl;
    }
};

class BlackPulsar : public Vehicle
{
public:
    void useVehicle()
    {
        std::cout << "Riding a Black Pulsar." << std::endl;
    }
};

class HondaActiva : public Vehicle
{
public:
    void useVehicle()
    {
        std::cout << "Riding a Honda Activa." << std::endl;
    }
};


class TransportMode
{
   public:
      virtual void use() = 0;
};

class VehicularTransportMode : public TransportMode
{
   public:
      VehicularTransportMode(Vehicle* v) : vehicle(v) {}
      virtual void use()
      {
         vehicle->useVehicle();
      }
      std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> vehicle;
};

class TrainTransportMode : public TransportMode
{
   virtual void use()
   {
      // Do the needful to use the train.
      std::cout << "Riding a train." << std::endl;
   }
};

class PedestrianTransportMode : public TransportMode
{
   virtual void use()
   {
      // Do the needful to use the feet :)
        std::cout << "Walking by foot." << std::endl;
   }
};

class FamilyMember
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<TransportMode> myTransportMode;
public:
    virtual void display() = 0;
    void setTransportMode(TransportMode *mode)
    {
        myTransportMode.reset(mode);
    }
    void transport()
    {
        myTransportMode->use();
    }
};

class Father : public FamilyMember
{
public:
    virtual void display()
    {
        std::cout << "I am Father" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Mother : public FamilyMember
{
public:
    virtual void display()
    {
        std::cout << "I am Mother" << std::endl;
    }
};


class Son : public FamilyMember
{
public:
    virtual void display()
    {
        std::cout << "I am Son" << std::endl;
    }
};


class Daughter : public FamilyMember
{
public:
    virtual void display()
    {
        std::cout << "I am Daughter" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    FamilyMember *fam = new Father();
    fam->display();
    fam->setTransportMode(new VehicularTransportMode(new FordFigo()));
    fam->transport();

    fam = new Daughter();
    fam->display();
    fam->setTransportMode(new VehicularTransportMode(new HondaActiva()));
    fam->transport();

    fam->setTransportMode(new TrainTransportMode());
    fam->transport();

    fam->setTransportMode(new PedestrianTransportMode());
    fam->transport();
    return 0;
}
```

**Additional Notes**

1. You have

   ```
   Vehicle *myVehicle;
   ```

   in the `public` section of the class. The corresponding line in my code,

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<TransportMode> myTransportMode;
   ```

   is in the `private` section of the class.
2. I've replaced the use of raw pointers by use of `std::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

1. It is very easy to alter the application behavior without changing its architecture.
2. It is very easy to implement new algorithms complying with the same interface can be easily introduced.
3. It is possible to switch the application strategies at run-time.
4. Strategy enables the clients to choose the required algorithm, without using a "switch" statement or a series of "if-else" statements.